# JS Replace characters with link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a block of text inside a div like:

```
<div id='t1'>
This is a great testing string.  Tomorrow grass is green.
</div>
```

and I want to replace all instance of the letter "g" with a link to google, like

```
<a href='www.google.com'>g</a>
```

Is it possible to do this with just Javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform a simple string replacement, the following will do:

```
var div = document.getElementById("t1");
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(/g/g, "<a href='http://www.google.com'>g</a>");
```

If you need more dynamics, e.g. substituting a word with a link, depending on the value, use:

Example: Replace g or G with different URLs:

```
var div = document.getElementById("t1");
var mapper = {
    g: "http://www.google.com",
    G: "http://stackoverflow.com"
};
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(/[Gg]/g, function(fullmatch){
    return "<a href='" + mapper[fullmatch] + "'>" + fullmatch + "</a>";
});
```

Comment: If I wanted to replace all instance of periods, then I'd use "/./g"?

Comment: You should use `\.`, because `.` matches all non-newline characters (a dot has a special meaning in RegExs).

Comment: `/word/g` is a Regular Expression which matches  "`word`". `/g` tells the `replace` function to continue matching until no match can be found (the default behaviour is to stop at the first match).

Comment: @RobW oh right! I thought wrong about `/g` before then! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

No jQuery required.

```
var t1 = document.getElementById('t1')
t1.innerHTML = t1.innerHTML.replace(/g/g, '<a href="http://www.google.com/">g</a>')
```

In `/g/g`, the first `g` is what you are searching for. The second `g` means **g**lobal (aka replace all)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#t1').html( $('#t1').text().replace(/g/g,"<a href='www.google.com'>g</a>") );
```

Comment: Note the use of `text` instead of another `html` word. **Advantage** is that `&gt;` will not be broken by replacement. It will instead be treated as `>` and still work in the end. Something lacking in mine and Rob's solutions. **Possibly dangerous disadvantage** is that `&lt;span onmouseover="..."&gt;` has the potential to introduce an [XSS vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), because the resulting text will be re-enstated as HTML `<span onmouseover="...">`. Therefore, this code should only be used if the original input is known to be safe.